# Get click button with Aframe and Angular

Tags: angular, aframe

How do I differentiate right and left click when I click on object in my 3d aframe scene with a mouse (in angular)?

I've tried just about every which way I can think of, a few that Chat thought up, and two directly from the documentation and the repo examples.

[This pr](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/pull/5088) suggests that this feature was introduced in 2022.

I am running the latest version 1.4.0.

and the current version of my code, based on [this example from the aframe repo](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/examples/test/cursor/mouse-events.html#L24) looks like this:

canvas.component.html

```
<a-scene vr-mode-ui="enabled: true">
  <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
  <a-assets timeout="5000">
    <a-asset-item id="garage-model" src="/assets/TheGarageV3.gltf"></a-asset-item>
  </a-assets>

  <a-entity id="mouseCursor" cursor="rayOrigin: mouse" raycaster="objects: .intersectable"></a-entity>

    <a-entity position="0 1 -3">
      <a-box color="black"
             my-click-event
             class="intersectable">
      </a-box></a-entity>

  /...///camera etc

</a-scene>
```

and then my canvas.component.ts

```
export class CanvasComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    AFRAME.registerComponent('my-click-event', {

      init () {
        this.el.addEventListener('click', this.click.bind(this));
        window.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());
      },
    
      click (event:any) {

        const mouseEvent = event.detail.mouseEvent;
        console.log(event.detail.intersection.point) // prints coords
        console.log(mouseEvent) //prints undefined.
        if (!mouseEvent) return;
        //code block never reached.
        if (mouseEvent.button === 0) {
          console.log("left button")
        } else if (mouseEvent.button === 1) {
          console.log("middle button")
        } else if (mouseEvent.button === 2) {
          console.log("right button")
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Am I working in the wrong version? I assumed latest would have this change per the PR.